# How to SHOW CREATE TABLE in a particular database in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

It is possible to get CREATE TABLE statement in specific database without using `USE` before?

Something like `SHOW CREATE TABLE my_table IN my_database;` (this doesn't works).

Thanks

Comment: I think that is not possible as we must have to choose database first using USE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
show create table database_name.table_name;
```